# What does $$ in php mean?

Tags: php

what does two back to back $ behind a variable means. Like this
$$id

where can I find more information on that
Thanks

Comment: *(reference)* http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In PHP, `$$` means you are about to inflict years of pain and suffering on at least one maintenance programmer. Note that you might wind up being that maintenance programmer.

It is a variable variable. Imagine this:

```
$quux = 'bar';
$foo[$quux] = "baz";
echo $foo['bar']; //prints baz
```

if there was no such thing as arrays, you might try something like this:

```
$quux = 'bar';
$$quux = "baz";
echo $bar; //prints baz
```

luckily we do have arrays so please don't use variable variables unless you are doing something convoluted and magical`*` and have no other choice.

`*`: Please don't do convoluted magical things, either.

Comment: You can make anything look convoluted with undescriptive variable names like that. Variable variables are just as maintainable as regular ones when named properly.

Comment: the foo, bar, baz, etc variables are very common when demonstrating a language feature. Obviously proper use of naming is a must in any language, but I'm talking about the maintainability of variable variables, not of dummy names -- I think they take much effort to use in a way that is not evil, so I'm okay with presenting them in a way that would make a novice programmer approach them with caution.

Answer (score 6):

These are called [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
$foo = 'bar';
$id = 'foo';

echo $id;  // prints foo
echo $$id; // prints bar
```

Answer (score 2):

in the PHP manual of course

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

note that it's obsolete and senseless syntax and you should always use arrays instead.